# Unable to read 900kb text file which has base64 conversion of the Image

Tags: android, json, file, stringbuilder

This is code I am using to read a file which includes Json format inside. File size is 901Kb. StringBuilder is unable to read the full file. It stops after 40 or 60 Lines.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    String fname = "visitdetails_JSONN.txt";
    String file_path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/VMS/";
    try 
    {
        text = new StringBuilder();
        file = new File(file_path, fname);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            //Log.e("Data", "File Found");
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            //Log.e("Data", text.toString());
        }
        else
            file.mkdirs();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you read a JSON file with a BufferedReader and not with [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

Comment: I am using Gson library to serialize the string values into a class.